# Why $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}, \sqrt[m]{q}):\mathbb{Q}] = nm$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

As title says, I want to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}, \sqrt[m]{q})$ is degree $nm$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ when $p \neq q$ are distinct primes. By Eisenstein's criterion, $x^{n} - p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb{Q}] = n$. However, I wonder if it is trivial that $x^{m} - q$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})$, assuming the general form of Eisenstein's criterion over integral domain (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) for the statement). I'm not sure if the polynomial satisfies assumptions of the Eisenstein's criterion.

Also, I tried some $p$-adic ($q$-adic will be more appropriate) strategy. *If we assume that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{Q}_{q}$*, then the irreducibility of $x^{m} - q$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})$ follows from it over $\mathbb{Q}_{q}$, which is a result of Newton polygon. However, the assumption fails in general, and when we enlarge $\mathbb{Q}_q$ to its finite extension that contains $\sqrt[n]{p}$, the situation gets worse.

Another direction (which I believe that shouldn't be easy) is to prove that the polynomial
$$
f(x) = \prod_{0\leq i < n, 0 \leq j < m} (x - \sqrt[n]{p}\zeta_{n}^{i} - \sqrt[m]{q}\zeta_{m}^{j})
$$
is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the claim follows from the another proposition $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p} + \sqrt[m]{q}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}, \sqrt[m]{q})$$ (this is not trivial, but I have a proof by the light use of Galois theory.) According to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26832/degree-of-sum-of-algebraic-numbers), this proposition implies our main claim when $n, m$ are coprime.

Can we use Eisenstein's criterion in this case? If not, is there a simple way to prove this?

Maybe related: [Why $\sqrt[3]{3}\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431221/why-sqrt33-not-in-mathbbq-sqrt32/2431390#2431390)

Comment: In the case of square roots there are several elementary ways. For the general result I think the simplest proofs use concepts from algebraic number theory. Most notably ramification of primes as $p$ is totally ramified in $\Bbb{Q}(\root n\of p)/\Bbb{Q}$ for all $n$, but usually unramified in $\Bbb{Q}(\root m\of q)/\Bbb{Q}$ (IIRC when $p\mid m$ you will need extras).

Comment: You might be able to reduce the question to the case where $m$ and $n$ are prime by Lang's Algebra, Theorem VI.9.1

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I agree with that. However, I think the splitting behavior of $q$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})$ is not trivial in general, as the ramified case you mentioned. By the way, if we assume that $q$ splits in the field, then can we use Eisenstein criterion in that case?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer Thank you! So at least the statement is true since the reduced case can be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elementary proof produced with the assistance of @KCd.

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[n]{p}$ and $\beta = \sqrt[m]{q}$ and
let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$.

If $i\not\equiv 0\pmod n$ and $j\not\equiv 0\pmod m$, then some minimal power $k>1$ of $\gamma=\alpha ^i\beta ^j$ is a rational. Now let $\omega$ be a primitive $k$th root of unity and consider the polynomial $x^k-\gamma ^k$ with roots  $$\gamma, \gamma \omega ,\gamma \omega ^2, ...,\gamma \omega ^{k-1}.$$
If $x^k-\gamma ^k$ is not a minimal polynomial for $\gamma $ over $\mathbb{Q}$, there would be a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with roots a non-trivial subset of  $\gamma, \gamma \omega ,\gamma \omega ^2, ...,\gamma \omega ^{k-1}$ and therefore with a product  $\gamma ^x\omega ^y\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $0<x<k$. Then $\omega ^y$ is real and is therefore $\pm 1$ and so $\gamma ^x\in \mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction of minimality.

We conclude that $x^k-\gamma ^k$ is a minimal polynomial. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\gamma )$ and then

$$\mathrm{Tr}_{L/\mathbb{Q}}(\gamma )=[L:K]\mathrm{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\gamma )=0.$$
Now suppose that there are rationals $a_{ij}$ such that  $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}a_{ij}\alpha ^i\beta ^j=0.$$
Then for any integers $u$ and $v$,  $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}a_{ij}\alpha ^{i-u}\beta ^{j-v}=0.$$

Taking $\mathrm{Tr}_{L/\mathbb{Q}}$ we see that $a_{ij}=0$ if  $i\equiv u\pmod n$ and $j\equiv u\pmod m$ and therefore  all $a_{ij}=0$. Then the $\alpha ^i\beta ^j$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=mn$.

Comment: The last paragraph is a bit handwavy on the details to explain how each coefficient can be brought down to the $(i,j) = (0,0)$ term.  That is why I had suggested in my previous comment on my own answer that you instead pick a hypothetical nonzero $(i,j)$-term for $i , j > 0$ that is appropriately minimal and then *divide* each remaining term by the corresponding $\alpha$ and $\beta$ powers to put that coefficient into the $(0,0)$ position to get a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. Finished at last I hope.

Comment: Actually, the argument at the end would go more smoothly if you replace $0 \leq i < n$ and $0 \leq j  < m$ at the start with "$i \not\equiv 0 \bmod n$ or $j \not\equiv 0 \bmod m$" so $i$ and $j$ could even be negative.  Then division by an individual term $\alpha^u\beta^v$ in the sum at the end turns each $\alpha^i\beta^j$ into $\alpha^{i-u}\beta^{j-v}$ which has trace $0$ as long as $(i,j) \not= (u,v)$ considering the range of summation at the end of the proof.

Comment: Yes, even better.

Comment: Thank you! This is much simpler than I thought and I don’t know why trace doesn’t come up in my mind...

Answer (score 2):

See the earlier question [$\operatorname{dim} \mathbb{Q}[2^{1/n},3^{1/m}] / \mathbb{Q} = nm$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962553/operatornamedim-mathbbq21-n-31-m-mathbbq-nm/3962682), where my answer explains why this problem over all $m$ and $n$ is equivalent to the case $m=n$ (for all $n$) and you can replace 2 and 3 with a more general pair of numbers in the base field.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, which I've now looked at and upvoted. Am I right in thinking that the only problem with a proof of the type I attempted is if $\alpha ^r $,  where $r$ is prime, or $\alpha ^4$ is in $Q(\beta )$?

Comment: @S.Dolan yes, I think so.

Comment: @S.Dolan the only gap in your new solution is saying you can multiply by any $\alpha^u\beta^v$ and run through it again. That kind of multiple wrecks the double sum running over $i$ and $j$ going from $0$ to $m$ or $n$. Change to dividing everything by a term at $(u,v)$ if lower-indexed coefficients are all $0$. That lets you formally maintain the range of double summation (or really shrink it, but at least not expand it). Tell me when the solution is made visible so I can delete my comments to it (no longer being about your current solution there).

Comment: No: if the coefficients are not all $0$ then let $u$ be minimal with $a_{uj} \not= 0$ for some $j$ and, for that $u$, let $v$ be minimal with $a_{uv} \not= 0$. Then the double sum has $a_{ij} = 0$ when $i<u$ for all $j$ and also when $i=u$ and $j<v$. Therefore you can proceed as I described in my previous comment. The trace argument will then imply $a_{uv} = 0$, a contradiction.